Is it valid to use L'Hopital's rule inside a power?
Suppose we have two functions such that f(a)=g(a)=0 and $f'(a)$ and $g'(a)$ are non-zero finite values. We are given to find $lim_{x\to a}\frac{(f(x))^2}{(g(x))^2}$ . So instead of differentiating $(f(x))^2$, can we differentiate f(x) directly? In other words, Is the above limit equivalent to $(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})^2$
And in a more general note, Can we apply this for any n-th power?

@ArielFishbein You are mistaken. The necessary condition is that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, and one uses the fact that $x^2$ is continuous.

This isn't about l'Hôpital's rule, it's a much more basic property of limits.
Let $g(x)$ be a function such that its limit as $x\to x_0$ equals $p\in\mathbb R$. 
That is, let $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x) = p$
Let $f(x)$ be a function continuous at $p$. Then:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(g(x)) = f\left(\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)\right)$$
Your question is just the case $f(x)=x^n$, that is everywhere continuous in $\mathbb R$ if $n>0$.
In short, the answer is yes.
